# About the PHP excution, it's line-by-line or file-by-file?

Tags: php

PHP is execute line by line or just like java that it's compiled form byte code to binary code file by file?

Comment: Lines do not matter in PHP (or C [besides preprocessed stuff], Java...) unlike Cobol or usually assembly. Lines exist to ease the work of the human programmer, but actually lengthen (a bit!) the first parsing work of the compiler/interpreter. Once compiled or parsed into bytecode, lines do not matter at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole files is parsed before anything get executed.
After this parser, PHP runs instruction by instruction. If your first instruction is a require/include, PHP will open the file and read their instructions (layered)

Answer (score 2):

PHP translates sources into opcode and after that evaluates it instruction by instruction.

Answer (score 2):

It's executed instruction by instruction. But before it gets executed, the whole file is parsed. Thus a syntax error occurs before anything gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can see PHP is not executed line-by-line, because you get syntax errors from whole file even before first line was executed (even in function which are not called at all).

If you want an example of line-by-line language, see Windows command line (it applies to unix sh files too) batch file language - you can type anything into lines which are not executed (for example because you terminate the file before the line gets parsed) and you won't get any kind of error.

Comment: Well the whole file is parsed prior to iterative execution.